# Python sqlalchemy sum on @property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following many to many relation:

```
class UserSupportProject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'usersupportprojects'
    user_id_supports = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id_project = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    project_tier = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    date_added = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    review = Column(Text, nullable=True)

    @property
    def get_project_tier(self):
        return object_session(self).query(ProjectTier).filter(ProjectTier.id == self.project_tier).first()
```

I need now to return the sum of the value of `project_tier` for a certain user `user_id_project`.

`project_tier` is only a reference. It is the `ID`.

I can get the data, such as the `tier_worth` with the property `get_project_tier`.

For example here I can see all numbers of the user:

```
star = User.query.filter_by(id=star_id).first()

for tier in star.user_gets_support:
    print (tier.get_project_tier.tier_worth)
```

I tested whether my sum code works and it does. I can calculate the sum of `project_tier`:

```
UserSupportProject.query.with_entities(func.sum(UserSupportProject.project_tier)).filter(UserSupportProject.user_id_project == star.id).scalar()
```

But it does not work with the actual `tier_worth`:

```
UserSupportProject.query.with_entities(func.sum(UserSupportProject.get_project_tier.tier_worth)).filter(UserSupportProject.user_id_project == star.id).scalar()
```

The error it gives:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'tier_worth'
```

Comment: properties only work on instances, you are trying to acces it from the class

Comment: Why not make `project_tier` a `ForeignKey` as well? Also your `user_id_supports` and `user_id_project` fields look wrong, maybe check the docs again.

Comment: what is wring with `user_id_supports` and `user_id_project`?

Answer (score 0):

Properties only work with instance. You will have to instantiate the class UserSupportProject or change the properties into a function.